# To retrieve image from Module

Tags: magento2, module, image, model

```
$image="<img src="echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Inchoo_Helloworld::images/Phone.jpg'
```

To know whether this code is correct to retrieve image from Module

Comment: show your module name & image path.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
$image = "<img src='".$this->getViewFileUrl('Inchoo_Helloworld::images/Phone.jpg')."/>";
```

instead of

```
$image="<img src="echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Inchoo_Helloworld::images/Phone.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

*you can use:-*

**imagepath in php** :-

```
   <?php  $path = $this->getViewFileUrl('Inchoo_Helloworld::images/icon.png'); ?>
```

**Html :-**

```
<img src="<?php echo $path ?>" alt="icon" height="20" width="20" />
```

Comment: retrieving more than one image means what should do? @Divyesh

Comment: is this code working? you have `$path` variable so, you can change 'icon.png' to other image path and put in `img` tag